# CSS right: -50 and transition not working

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following HTML/CSS

```css
.cart-preview .body {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
  right: -20;
}

.cart-preview:hover .body {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <div class="cart-subtotals">
    <div class="products">
      <span class="label">Subtotal</span>
      <span class="value">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <span class="label"></span>
      <span class="value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="shipping">
      <span class="label">Shipping</span>
      <span class="value">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <span class="label"></span>
      <span class="value"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-total">
    <span class="label">Total sum</span>
    <span class="value">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have the `.body` class taking all of the display's height, which works fine for the bottom, but at the top there's a space not filled, despite position fixed. The right attribute also does not work, as well as the transition.

The element is positioned more right, but all values I enter for `right:`, don't matter, the div stays at the same position.
I want to have a fly-in animation on-hover, maybe someone can help me with the right and height alignment.

BTW: This is an MVCE. The body div is nested within other divs and most of them are position relative, so I used position fixed for the body and did not post the other divs the body is nested in.

Comment: `right` needs a unit when not `0`

Comment: @chazsolo is correct here. You need to set `right: -20px` or `right: -20%` or or some other unit of your choice.

Comment: adding a unit does not change the effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`right:-20;` is not working. You should define measurement units there. Now transition also working fine in my fiddle.

Check and let me know if there is any problem here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/Lwebxhkn/8/

```css
.cart-preview {
  position:relative;
}

.cart-preview .body {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
  right: -20px;
}
.cart-preview:hover .body {
  visibility: visible;
  position: fixed;
  transition: right 1s linear;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-preview">
  <span>cart preview</span>
  <div class="body">
      <ul>
              </ul>
      <div class="cart-subtotals">
                  <div class="products">
            <span class="label">Subtotal</span>
            <span class="value">0</span>
          </div>
                  <div class="">
            <span class="label"></span>
            <span class="value"></span>
          </div>
                  <div class="shipping">
            <span class="label">Shipping</span>
            <span class="value">0</span>
          </div>
                  <div class="">
            <span class="label"></span>
            <span class="value"></span>
          </div>
              </div>
      <div class="cart-total">
        <span class="label">Total sum</span>
        <span class="value">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding a unit but it did not work, so i changed directly in the css (not in the chrome instant editor, had a unit there too, thats why is asked) and now it works:)

Comment: @ItFreak, it's my pleasure :)

Comment: But maybe you can help me why the height does not take the full screen and leaves some space at the top

Comment: @ItFreak check jsfiddle link below.
http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/Lwebxhkn/11/
Is that you asked from me ?

Comment: Yes, but for me it does not work, leave space above where other divs are placed. can i 'overwrite' them? z-index is set already

Comment: @ItFreak, not possible to say exactly that solution is working..Could you send me a link of working environment?

Comment: @ItFreak, apply top: 0;  and updated styles should be like this
.cart-preview .body {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #dbd4d4;
    right: -20px;
    top: 0;
}

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot about you :/ i tred the top 0 myself and well, dirty but works:D

Comment: @ItFreak, Ok :)